# Basic site layout and navigation

Tags: css, html

I was asked to make a simple webpage for a small project of a local art gallery I'm helping out.
The problem is that my HTML knowledge is out of date. I started to make it using tables but it turns out to be harder that I thought.

[Here's a basic design mockup.](https://imgur.com/a/kFL6D)

- **Blue** is a header and have a width of 100%.
- **Green** is main body of the site, it has fixed width (say 800px) and goes to the bottom of the screen.
- **Yellow** is footer its attached at the bottom inside main body.
- **Red** is navblocks and its my main problem. They are fixed width (say 180px) with text inside them aligned left. They a equally spaced form one another and leftmost and rightmost ones are aligned with the ends of the main body, but move closer as you shrink screen width.

After some googling I manage to make equally spaced navblocks using spans and "text-align:center" but that also makes text inside navblocks align to center.

To make them align with the ends of the main body, I was going to use some sort of container with the fixed width (180 + 800 + 180) but whenever I try it it brakes the spans alignment.

So my question is: how do I approach this navblocks?

Comment: Please tell if the site is mobile friendly and if you use any framework like Bootstrap.

Comment: share your code please

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your Question , Here is a small codepen link. Hope It helps.

[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/swapnaranjitanayak/pen/ZByJRm%60)

HTML:

```
<header>
  <nav>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a> 
      <a href="#">Link 2</a> 
      <a href="#">Link 3</a> 
      <a href="#">Link4</a>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus aperiam, debitis labore ratione doloribus adipisci quia repellat voluptatem tempora laborum vel possimus dolorum numquam, esse, dignissimos qui iste, assumenda laudantium. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat recusandae provident similique nemo, hic delectus dolorem totam, minima maiores quas, distinctio dolorum. Numquam aperiam, rem consectetur tempora, tempore dignissimos. Recusandae.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam voluptatum recusandae dolorem necessitatibus, vel nihil possimus voluptate obcaecati dignissimos, magni repellat, iusto atque, provident? Veniam error quaerat iusto, et explicabo?
  </div>

  <footer>
     footer
  </footer>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
header{
  background:blue;
  padding:10px 0;
   border-bottom:2px solid #000;
}
nav {
  width: 80%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
nav a{
  color:#fff;
  width:20%;
  text-align:center;
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper{
  width:800px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color:green;
  color:#fff;
}
.content{
    padding:20px ;
}
footer{
  background:yellow;
  padding:20px;
  color:#000;
}
```